# How can I properly test PHP scripts that have been POSTed to using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm struggling to work out how to test my code.

I have a script in PHP which takes values from a string and puts them together into a message to be mailed.

The form is submitted using AJAX as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions/sendForm.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: console.log('Success!')
});
```

The data is supposed to be passed to the PHP script. The var `dataString` looks like this:

```
var dataString = 'name='+name+'&company='+company+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&message='+message+'&signup='+signUp;
```

I am then trying to access these vars as such:

```
parse_str($dataString);

echo $name;
echo $company;
echo $email;
echo $phone;
echo $message;
echo $signUp;
```

My issue is that something is not happening, and I cannot test my PHP script any more because I am submitting via AJAX, so I never actually hit the script with the correct data.

**How can I test a script working/echo variables etc when the form is submitted via AJAX**?

Comment: Why not simply setup a debugger like XDebug or so? If you are using an IDE that supports, testing it things like this are a breeze.

Comment: First, use a developer tool like firebug to make sure the ajax gets submitted. Then, use `print_r($_POST);` in PHP like @n-dru suggested, then move on to the next step. Always take the same steps that data does and you will never have debugging problems.

Comment: _“I am then trying to access these vars as such: `parse_str($dataString);`”_ – and where is that PHP variable `$dataString` supposed to come from …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the method is `POST`, just echo the `$_POST` value:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Or, like in your example, but instead of `parse_str` use `extract`:

```
extract($_POST);

echo $name;
echo $company;
echo $email;
echo $phone;
echo $message;
echo $signUp;
```

And in your `ajax` function change `success` to:

```
success: function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

to see what was printed in `PHP` script.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Developer Tools console. Most major browsers have them built in and accessible using the F12 key. Look at the Network tab (in Chrome) to see all the network traffic, including any Ajax calls. You can click on the ajax call to see the response. Anything you echo in your PHP file will be in the response.

So if you use `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP file you can check if the values are there as expected. In Chrome you can also look at the headers tab to see what data was sent by Ajax.